# Как определить на каком яп написан сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование

Разумеется банальные .php/.pl/.jsp/и т.д. и http headers не в счёт

p.s. В качестве примера Хэшкод. В хедарах не написано. Как определить, что он написан на Go (узнал из записей в блоге)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что некоторые сайты написаны на смеси языков. Более того, даже то, что выглядит как одна страница, по факту может генерироваться скриптами на нескольких языках.

В некоторых случаях можно попробовать опознать движок (типа  drupal, joomle, wordpress), а там будет понятнее. В других случаях можно попытаться подсунуть неверные данные (например, исказить get запрос - вместо цифр подсунуть кавычки) и посмотреть на сгенерированную ошибку. Конечно, программисты стараются такое убирать, но для анализа иногда достаточно нескольких байт. По таким ошибкам иногда можно опознать не то, что язык программирования, а и точные версии интерпретаторов-компиляторов.

Но проблема в том, что такой анализ часто граничит со взломом и в  некоторых случаях будет очень тяжело доказать, что просто "хотел посмотреть версию php, а не дропнуть базу".